# Displaying a message box after selecting value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dialog, messagebox

i want to show a message box when the ajax autocomplete value is selected to the certain textfield. i'm using [jquery-confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#options) js library for this. here is my code.

```
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        console.log( ui.item.value );
                        nic= ui.item.value;
                        $("#msgbox").open();
                        return false;
                    }
```

.

```
    $("#msgbox").confirm({
        title: 'Entry Found',
        content: 'msg',
        lazyOpen:true,
        buttons: {
            confirm: function () {
                $.alert('Confirmed!');
            },
            cancel: function () {
                $.alert('Canceled!');
            },
```

ps: i'm so new to js and these jquery stuffs.:)

Comment: You may have to do `$('#msgbox').confirm().open()`.  The api says that the open method is available off of the 'jc' object returned from the confirm initialization.

Comment: i tried it,not working :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i found the problem, `select` should be outside of the jquery `source` ,here is the complete code;

```
$("#nic").autocomplete({
            minLength:5,
            source : function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajaxautocomplete.html",
                    type: "Post",
                    data:JSON.stringify({"nic": request.term}),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success : function(data) {
                        response($.map(data.patient, function (patient) {
                            return{
                                label: patient.nic,
                                id: patient.id,
                            }
                        }))
                    }
                });
            },

            select: function( event, ui ) {
               //msg confirm box
                return true
            }
        });
```

and the dialog box was not working, i used jquery-confirm box.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this. Instead of 'confirm' use 'dialog'.Call like this inside 'select'.

```
$("#msgbox").dialog("open");
```

And

```
$("#msgbox").dialog({
    title: 'Entry Found',
    content: 'msg',
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    lazyOpen:true,
    buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
            alert('Confirmed!');},
        cancel: function () {
            alert('Canceled!');}
}
});
```

Comment: hi,i tried this ,it also not working, i just found that console log under `select` is not firing when i select a value from autosuggested value from the menu. why is that

Comment: Hi, please post your code in plunker or something. So it will be helpful to figure out the bug.